# MongoDB/Mongoose update parent objects and nested array from document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Hello everyone,

I am trying to update an object that is on the root of the document and a specific array object that is nested two within another array.

This is how my Mongoose Schema looks like this:

```
{
  name: String,
  group_total: Number,
  members: [
   user_id: { type: String, index: true },
   purchases:[
    purchase_id: { type: String, index: true },
    cost: Number
   ]
  ]
}
```

I would like to update the document from:

```
{
      name: 'example',
      group_total: 100,
      members: [
       user_id: '123',
       purchases:[
        purchase_id: '456',
        cost: 20
       ]
      ]
    }
```

To:

```
{
      name: 'example',
      group_total: 120,
      members: [
       user_id: '123',
       purchases:[
        purchase_id: '456',
        cost: 40
       ]
      ]
    }
```

Where the content of members is the object of index `i` from an array of length `n` and the content of purchases is the object of index `j` from an array of length `m`

I cannot seem to update the nested object `cost` within the arrays but I can easily update the root object `group_total`

My query right now is as follows:

```
Group.update(
    {
      _id: ObjectId(req.body.group_id),
      members: {
        $elemMatch: {
          user_id: req.body.user_id }
        }
      },
    {
      $set: {
        group_total: req.body.cost,
        'members.$[mem].providers.$[prov].title': req.body.title,
      }
    },
    {
      multi: true,
      arrayFilters: [
        { 'mem.user': user_id: req.body.user_id } },
        { 'prov.purchase_id': req.body.purchase_id }
      ]
    }
  )
```

I used this MongoDB doc [url as a reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

Comment: There is a typo in field name in arrayFilters ( purcahse_id should be purchase_id and user should be user_id ) and also nested array should be purchases in the set.. Try something like `Group.update(
    {"members.user_id": '123' },
    {
      $set: {
        group_total: 120,
        'members.$[mem].purchases.$[pur].cost': 40,
      }
    },
    {
      multi: true,
      arrayFilters: [
        { 'mem.user_id': '123' },
        { 'pur.purchase_id': '456' }
      ]
    }
  )`

Comment: @Veeram I am very sorry the typo was a mistake on my part. I reduced the size of the schema from what I have and instead only included the information that was relevant to the query. I updated the question by fixing the typos. Thanks!